# How to change authentication type in jhipster created application

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, spring-websocket

I have created my project which required spring web socket using Jhipster with **Token based authentication**. Lately I found that Token based authentication does not work with spring web socket from [here](https://jhipster.github.io/using-websockets/). How to change authentication type without recreating application from beginning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the `.yo-rc.json` file from your project to a new directory, edit it to change the value of the `authenticationType` property to "session" or "oauth2", and then run `jhipster`, this will re-generate your app without asking the questions. You can then compare with your project and update it accordingly.

If you want to re-create your entities, you can copy the `.jhipster` folder and re-generate your project using `jhipster --with-entities`

Comment: To zoom in to the session change only copy the .yo-rc.json file to two dirs. in one you change the authenticationType and the other not, now compare both and you will see the changes for authentication type only